# Rails query for a social network feed

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The architecture of the model is simple.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hunts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :user_hunts, dependent: :destroy
end

class Hunt < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :user_hunts, dependent: :destroy
end

class UserHunt < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :hunt
end
```

`User` can create hunts . Other `Users` can see these `hunts` in their feed. They can either accept it or reject it. This would create a row in `UserHunt` with `hunt_id` and `user_id`. So what I want is a result of `Hunt` which satisfy these onditions.

- `Hunt` is not his own (`hunt.user_id != id`)
- `User` has not seen the hunt before ( This is the part which I am finding difficult to implement)

After lot of trials this is what I came up  with.

```
Hunt.left_outer_joins(:user_hunts)
    .where('user_hunts.user_id != ? OR user_hunts.user_id is null AND hunts.user_id != ?',id,id)
```

But this has a problem of selecting `hunts` which other users have subscribed.

This is a common scenario in websites I believe. But I was not able to find any solution here.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use a subquery to select all read `Hunt` records which will be excluded from the main query. This will give you all `Hunt` records that are not created and read by a `User`(params[:id])

```
Hunt.where.not(user_id: params[:id])
    .where.not(id: UserHunt.select(:hunt_id).where(user_id: params[:id]))
```